# Should the composer package name in a laravel project be edited?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I'm making a custom application using Laravel. By default Laravel generates a composer.json file like the following:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
}
```

Is it good practice to change the name, description, license etc on my project?

More info: I am developing this project for another company. They will use it internally (as a public website) and may or may not hire a different developer in the future.

Comment: You'd only change this if you're going to be offering the application on packagist.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, changing it provides no real benefit unless you're planning to release the project as a composer projects that allows people to run `composer create-project you/yourproject`.

There's no real rule around changing if you plan to keep it internal only, but there are two arguments, one for and one against.

1. Changing it keeps it simple, and gives developers working on your project a nice little source to some basic information.
2. Keeping it as the default allows you and other developers to access some basic information about the systems creation.

So ultimately, it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should edit it to reflect the current state. At least delete info that you don't want, like the MIT license (you probably don't want to license proprietary code that way), the keywords, description and name.

Maybe in the future, `composer create-project` will deal with it more properly (the source project needs to have a name to be identifiable, but creating a project almost never needs to keep that name) - but this also won't help you with existing projects.

Keep that meta data correct (at least delete incorrect data) - you never know the benefits. Personally, I hugely like having the right project names because that name gets displayed on my Satis pages as "projects using this package", i.e. the reverse dependency - so I know what to update if I change a library.

Comment: The second paragraph answers the question best for me, I was not sure if projects should keep the same info as the source project. The code will be proprietary and I am developing this for another company so it's probably good to have my name and my company name in it.